# If there is an error postgresql trigger how will I catch the exception in python server api code?

Tags: python, postgresql, triggers

I have a postgresql trigger which throws out an exception while editing a record is not permitted. The python API call snippet is as follows:

```
try:
    stmt = tab1.update().values(new_data).\
           where(tab1.c.id == emp_id)
    g.conn.execute(stmt)
except Exception, e:
    return jsonify({"message":"Not allowed"}), 400
```

Is this the correct way to catch the exception thrown out by the trigger invoked ? Can I get more information about the exception(from the trigger) in my python api call?